# CSS not working from relative path with php 'includes'

Tags: php, html, css

folder structure

```
 /
 |--index.php

 +--includes
 |--header.html

 +--css
 |--style.css
```

I have 2 subfolders in my main project folder.  One is a folder called 'includes' and the other one is called 'css'. 
I have my 
-`index.php` file in the main folder
-`header.html` in my `'main/includes'` folder
-`style.css` in my `'main/css'` folder

My index.php includes the header.html like this:`include_once('includes/header.html');` (this Works!)

My header.html file links the css like this:`<link href='../css/style.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'/>`
(this does NOT work!)

I don't understand why the css file is not loaded.
I have tried using the base tag, although I'm not sure I'm using it right. 
`<base href="http://localhost/main" />` (this is NOT working)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try using

```
<link href='css/style.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'/>
```

As `index.php` and the `css` folder lie at the same level.

With

`<link href='../css/style.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'/>`,

you are asking your server to look after the `style.css` in upper level directory of `index.php` which does not exist.

You can also use `/` because, it points do the document root of the website.

```
<link href="/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: <link href="/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> does not work.

Comment: <link href='css/style.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'/> THIS WORKS!! thanks!

Comment: I was struggling with this exact same problem and when I read your answer I literally had to facepalm. It's so incredibly obvious, but I was thinking of the header.html as being nested in a folder. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you understand how `include` works. Essentially the code in the referenced file will be copied into the main file, and then processed. So if you're including it into `index.php`, then you want to reference the CSS file accordingly.

The following should work:

```
<link href="/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

You'll find it is the most easy to just use absolute paths when using HTML, that way the above like will still be valid, even if you copy it to a file that is in within a folder besides the root.

Answer (score 2):

`$siteurl ="http://localhost/project";`

(store this variable in config file so that you can use globally)

```
<link href='../css/style.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'/>
```

will be changed to

```
<link href='<?php echo $siteurl;?>/css/style.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

just change from `<link href='../css/style.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'/>` to `<link href='css/style.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'/>`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add CSS in html file using PHP `require`:

```
<style><?php require("css/style.css");?></style>
```

**Note**: `<style>` tag is important otherwise it will echo plain text