# css in php include page to main page

Tags: php, html, css

I have two pages: one.php and two.php

i included two.php (**include 'two.php';**) in one.php

two.php has styles(**link rel css**) which is not being included in one.php

how can I solve the issue?

more over in two.php I have some styles that needed to be mixed with the styles of one.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS not working from relative path with php 'includes'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27054686/css-not-working-from-relative-path-with-php-includes)

Comment: It's most likely wrong relative pathing. If you use include, stylesheet pathing is relative from two.php

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"> in two.php. but when I included the page in one.php, then css of two.php is not coming in one.php